# How to encrypt and decrypt AES-256-cbc in Java like openssl with given key and IV

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes

First problem: 
I have encrypted text by openssl, in the first step i generated key

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -k abcdefghasd -P -md sha256
```

generated output

```
key=E640008145BBB4B8DEF141BBF20301C2017D3DB7ABE56DEBCF95D412B03B61F2
iv =868CB4028A265D33B0EAE131EF72F3AB
```

then i try encrypt password using

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k E640008145BBB4B8DEF141BBF20301C2017D3DB7ABE56DEBCF95D412B03B61F2 -iv 868CB4028A265D33B0EAE131EF72F3AB -base64 <<< hashingpassword
```

In the next step i try decrypt this in Java

```java
public String decrypt(String encryptedPassword) {
    try {
        String myKey = "E640008145BBB4B8DEF141BBF20301C2017D3DB7ABE56DEBCF95D412B03B61F2";
        byte[] decodeKey = Hex.decodeHex(myKey.toCharArray());
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(decodeKey, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(Hex.decodeHex("868CB4028A265D33B0EAE131EF72F3AB")));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedPassword)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

And i got error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption
```

What im doing wrong?
I'm new to the chapter on encryption

---

Problem is resolved by uppercase K in openssl command encryption

---

Comment: Regarding your second OpenSSL statement: The (hex encoded) key is passed with *-K* (with *-k* a password is passed), s. [openssl enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html), i.e. your second OpenSSL statement also interprets the key material as password and performs a key derivation again, which is why the decryption with the Java code fails. Therefore, in the second OpenSSL statement replace `-k` with `-K` and try again.

Comment: Its working! Thank you very much for help. Now i have problem with encryption,  I edited my post and put encryption code, check if you have time